# Plot two rasters with different extents

Tags: raster, r, extents, plot

I have two rasters with different extents that overlap partly:

```
ext1 <- extent(99500,700500,249500,600500)
ext2 <- extent(1356,643990,269903,690810)

#create rasters
rr1 <- raster(matrix(runif(1000000,0,100), 1000, 1000))
rr2 <- raster(matrix(runif(1000000,0,100), 1000, 1000))

extent(rr1) <- ext1
extent(rr2) <- ext2
```

How can I plot both rasters in one plot?

I've tried

```
ext3 <- extent(min(ext1[1],ext2[1]),max(ext1[2],ext2[2]),
               min(ext1[3],ext2[3]),max(ext1[4],ext2[4]))
plot(rr1, ext = ext3)
```

But the only the `extent` of `rr1` is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge the extents (which saves all that min/max stuff!) and plot the extent, then add the rasters:

```
em = merge(extent(rr1),extent(rr2))
plot(em, type="n")
plot(rr1,add=TRUE, legend=FALSE)
plot(rr2, add=TRUE, legend=FALSE)
```

Use `type="n"` so a box isn't drawn round the extent. Use `legend=FALSE` or you get two overlapping legends.

From experiments it seems to me that `plot(r, ext=e)` only has an effect if `e` is within `r`, in other words for focusing on a part of a raster, not zooming out. The help sort of implies this:

```
 ext: An extent object to zoom in a region (see also ‘zoom’ and
      ‘crop(x, drawExtent())’
```